# Derivative of a bounded Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Just revising for my advanced calculus exam and came across this question:

> Consider the function $f(x)$ defined by the integral equation:
>   $$
> f(x) = x^2 + \int_0^x(x − t)f(t) dt.
> $$
>   Derive an $ODE$ and boundary conditions for $f(x)$, and solve this
>   to determine $f(x)$.

I would assume you take the derivative of both sides to get:

$$
f'(x) = 2x + {d \over dx}{\int_0^x(x − t)f(t) dt}.
$$

But where do I go from here? My first guess is:

$$
f'(x) = 2x + (x-x)f(x) - x.f(0).
$$
$$
f'(x) = 2x  - x.f(0).
$$

Surely that's wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest that you break up the integral into two separate integrals.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 That is a bit rude.

Comment: Is the derivative of $F(x)$ not simply $f(x)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$f (x)=x^2+x\int_0^xf (t)dt-\int_0^xtf (t)dt $$
and by FTC,
$$f'(x)=2x+\int_0^xf (t)dt+xf (x)-xf (x)$$
$$=2x+\int_0^xf (t)dt $$

> $$f''(x)=2+f (x) $$
>
> $$f (x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}-2$$
>   and since $f (0)=f'(0)=0$, we find
>
> $$f (x)=e^x+e^{-x}-2=4\sinh^2 (\frac {x}{2}) $$

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for more details.  You're right about the $(x-x) f(x)$ term, but the second term should be $\int_0^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x-t) f(t) dt = \int_0^x f(t) dt$. The ODE you derive turns out to be second order.

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$ f(x) = x^2 + \int_0^x(x − t)f(t) dt=f(x) = x^2 + x\int_0^x f(t)dt-\int_0^x tf(t) dt.
$$
So $f(0)=0$. Taking derivative gives
$$　f'(x) = ２x + \int_0^x f(t)dt+xf(x)- xf(x)=2x+\int_0^xf(t)dt
$$
and hence $f'(0)=0$.
Taking derivative again gives
$$　f''(x) = 2+f(x). $$
So $f(x)$ satisfies the following 2nd order DE
$$ y''-y=2,y(0)=y'(0)=0 $$
whose solution is
$$ y=e^x+e^{-x}-2. $$